# FIX MYSQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in Linux

Tags: mysql

I installed MySQl but I get the following logs:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
xadmin`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will work:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p <hit enter>
<enter password>
```